# Apex controller to check the availability of chosen time

Tags: visualforce

I have a name and checkbox on my visualforce page. When the checkbox is clicked, it will check if the name already has an appointment on that time. how can i achieve this in controller. Any sample code will help. Thank you.

```
public with sharing class wrapper_test_controller {
public list<sched> schedules{get;set;}

 public wrapper_test_controller(){
 schedules = new List<sched>();

    list<teacher__c> object1 = [select id,name, First_name__c, Subject__c, Room_assignment__c from teacher__c ];

    list<schedule__c> object2 = [Select id, name, teacher__c, time__c, student__c, parent__c from schedule__c ];

    for(teacher__c teacher : object1){
        schedules.add(new sched(teacher));
    }
    for (schedule__c time1: object2){
        schedules.add(new sched(time1));
    }

}
public class sched{
    public Id tid {get;set;}
    public Id sid {get;set;}
    public Name sname {get;set;}
    public string steacher{get;set;}
    public string tlname{get;set;}
    public string tfname{get;set;}
    public string sparent{get;set;}
    public string sstudent{get;set;}
    public string time1{get;set;}
    public string room{get;set;}
    public string tsubject{get;set;}


public sched(teacher__c object1){
this.tid = object1.id;
this.tlname = object1.name;
this.tfname = object1.first_name__c;
this.tsubject = object1.subject__c;
this.room = object1.room_assignment__c;
}
public sched(schedule__c object2){

this.sid = object2.id;
this.steacher = object2.teacher__c;
this.oras= object2.time__c;
this.sstudent =object2.student__c;
this.sparent =object2.parent__c;

}
}
}

public with sharing class checkTime {

    public list<schedTime> schedule{get;set;}



     List<schedule__c > schList= [select id, teacher__c, time__c from schedule__c 
             where time__c =: sched.time1 and teacher__c =: sched.teacher];

    if(schList.size() > 0){
   apexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(Apexpages.severity.error, 
   'Please select another time. this  time already taken.'));
   }

   }
```

the error is unexpected token public

Comment: that time means current time?  and where it will check on which object?

Comment: no, the time__c is a picklist in the visualforce page. it will be saved as text. It will check in a custom object schedule__c

Comment: @TusharSharma..

Answer (score 0):

I will not write complete code for you. but I can suggest you method which you can use to solve this problem.

Now whenever the checkbox is checked using some `actionfunction` or `action:support` then in the controller query on the `schedule__c` object like

```
List<schedule__c > schList= [select id from schedule__c where time__c =: selectTime and user__c =: selected user];
if(schList.size() > 0)
   apexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(Apexpages.severity.error, 'Please select another time. this  time already taken.'));
```

follow this approach this will solve your problem.

Comment: please see the code above I have an error